# How to return N1qlQueryResult as the response of REST API for Couchbase databse?

Tags: java, json, spring, nosql, couchbase

I want to return the `N1qlQueryResult` as a response of my `REST API`. Below is the code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> get() {
    List<N1qlQueryRow> result = null;
    try {
        Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create("localhost");
        Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket("myBucket", "xyz");
        bucket.bucketManager().createN1qlPrimaryIndex(true, false);
        N1qlQueryResult queryResult = bucket.query(N1qlQuery.simple("select * FROM myBucket"));
        queryResult.forEach(System.out::println);
        result = queryResult.allRows();
    } catch (final Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(result); 
}
```

I get error message:

> Could not write content: No serializer found for class
>   com.couchbase.client.java.query.DefaultN1qlQueryRow and no properties
>   discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable
>   SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain:
>   java.util.ArrayList[0]); nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer
>   found for class com.couchbase.client.java.query.DefaultN1qlQueryRow
>   and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid
>   exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through
>   reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])

What is the solution? I want to return response as `JSON`.

Answer (score 3):

`ObjectMapper` by default fails when bean is `empty`. We can disable this like below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
```

but in your case it does not solve a problem because result will be empty anyway. There is no good idea to return `type`-s which do not represent `POJO` itself. `N1qlQueryResult` and `DefaultAsyncN1qlQueryRow` do not have classic `getters` and `Jackson` does not recognise methods alike `value()` by default. I propose to create `Map<String, Object>` and build required output and include needed properties manually:

```
Map<String, Object> n1QlResult = new HashMap<>();
n1QlResult.put("status", result.status());
// other ...
n1QlResult.put("rows", result.allRows()
        .stream()
        .map(i -> i.value().toMap())
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

and finally return:

```
return ResponseEntity.ok(n1QlResult);
```

Of course, when you have many methods like this you can write common layer which translates these kind of object to `Map` or write custom serialiser and configure `ObjectMapper` user by `Spring` container.

EDIT
In case you want to return only rows return:

```
result.allRows()
        .stream()
        .map(i -> i.value().toMap())
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: But it returns the bucket name with each item, I have already written a similar type of code. What I want is simple json, for example if rows in db are like: 1st row: {"key1":"value1"}, 2nd row:{"key2":"value2"}.   The output should be like : [{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}].

Comment: @iAmLearning, see my update. Just convert `N1qlQueryResult` to list of object using `Stream API` or `foreach` to list of `Map`-s.