# No serializer found for class in custom Java AWS application

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, aws-sdk

I am creating a Spring application where in it calls information from the AWS API and converts it to JSON for a front end application to digest and display. I am currently trying to return a list out all of the current S3 buckets on an account but am running into an issue where the JSON response is:

> status": 500,
>   "error": "Internal Server Error",
>   "message": "Type definition error: [simple type, class software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.Bucket]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.Bucket and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.landsend.clouddashboard.data.Class.S3[\"bucketList\"]-java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0])",
>   "path": "/api/s3/buckets"

I have created a class called S3 that has private variables. One of them being a List type with the name bucketList. This class has the representative getters and setters as well associated with those variables.

I have also tried adding this to the applications.properties file:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false
```

This did result in the error disappearing but I ended up with an empty JSON file.

**Controller Class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/api")
public class S3Controller {

    @Autowired
    private S3Service s3Service;

    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET, value="/s3/buckets")
    public S3 ListBuckets(){
        return s3Service.listBucket();
    }
}
```

**Service Class**

```
@Service
public class S3Service {

    private S3Access s3Access;

    @Autowired
    public S3Service(S3Access s3Access){
        this.s3Access = s3Access;
    }
    public S3 listBucket(){
        //Any Additional business logic would go here
        return s3Access.listBucket();
    }
}
```

**Access Class**

```
@Repository
public class S3Access implements S3Repository {

    @Autowired
    private S3 s3Instance;

    private Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
    private S3Client s3Client = 
                     S3Client.builder().region(region).build();

    @Override
    public S3 listBucket() {
        ListBucketsRequest listBucketsRequest = ListBucketsRequest.builder().build();
        ListBucketsResponse listBucketsResponse = s3Client.listBuckets(listBucketsRequest);
        s3Instance.setBucketList(listBucketsResponse.buckets());
        return s3Instance;
    }
}
```

**S3 Constructor Class**

```
@Component
public class S3 {
    private String fileName;
    private String bucketName;
    private int bucketSize;
    private List<Bucket> bucketList;

    public List<Bucket> getBucketList() {
        return bucketList;
    }

    public void setBucketList(List<Bucket> bucketList) {
        this.bucketList = bucketList;
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on why this isn't working is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is with [Bucket](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/Bucket.html) class. `Jackson` by default treats all provided objects like `POJO`-s. Each `POJO` should have list of `getters`/`setters`. In case, class does not have them object is treated as empty. If you want to serialise classes like this you can:

1. Create extra `POJO` class with `getters` and map it from raw `AWS`
   class to this `POJO`.
2. Implement and register serialiser for this class.
3. Convert `AWS` model to `Map`-s and `List`-s manually and serialise them.

See also:

- [How to return N1qlQueryResult as the response of REST API for Couchbase databse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55179768/how-to-return-n1qlqueryresult-as-the-response-of-rest-api-for-couchbase-databse)

Comment: Can someone expand on this? Which one is easiest/recommended? Are there any examples?

Comment: @MarkHu, it depends from your case. Create a new question, link to this one, and show your code. easiest/recommended depends from the given usecase.

Comment: @MarkHu call its `toBuilder()` method, and it returns a `BuilderImpl` ,which dose have standard getter/setter methods,and can be  serialized properly by jackson-json
@see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/76503602/13655996

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer above, another method of solving this problem is to extract the parts of the list and insert them as their separated, respective lists into the prebuilt POJO.

In this example, I took the `name()` and `creationDate()` functions and put them in their own list in the S3 Class. This allows Jackson to read the S3 Class and get the required information without having to build an extra POJO for the `Bucket` class. Not entirely sure which way is actually cleaner or more effective but this also worked for what I was doing.

**S3 Construction Class**

```
@Component
public class S3 {
    private ArrayList<String> bucketList;
    private ArrayList<Instant> bucketCreationDate;

    public ArrayList<Instant> getBucketCreationDate() {
        return bucketCreationDate;
    }

    public void setBucketCreationDate(ArrayList<Instant> bucketCreationDate) {
        this.bucketCreationDate = bucketCreationDate;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getBucketList() {
        return bucketList;
    }

    public void setBucketList(ArrayList<String> bucketList) {
        this.bucketList = bucketList;
    }
}
```

**Access Class**

```
@Repository
public class S3Access implements S3Repository {

    @Autowired
    private S3 s3Instance;

    private Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
    private S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder().region(region).build();
    private ArrayList <String> bucketNameList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList <Instant> bucketCreationDate = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public S3 listBucket() {
        ListBucketsRequest listBucketsRequest = ListBucketsRequest.builder().build();
        ListBucketsResponse listBucketsResponse = s3Client.listBuckets(listBucketsRequest);

        // Adding Bucket Names to Array List
        for (int i = 0; i < listBucketsResponse.buckets().size() ; i++) {
            bucketNameList.add(listBucketsResponse.buckets().get(i).name());
        }

        // Adding Bucket Creation Dates to Array List
        for (int i = 0; i < listBucketsResponse.buckets().size() ; i++) {
            bucketCreationDate.add(listBucketsResponse.buckets().get(i).creationDate());
        }

        // Setting the lists in the S3 Class
        s3Instance.setBucketCreationDate(bucketCreationDate);
        s3Instance.setBucketList(bucketNameList);

        return s3Instance;
```

Answer (score 0):

apparently  the builder class is serializable (since they have public getters).I have tried it on the findings returned by getFindigs API for GuardDuty in a restController class and it did serialize the object successfully. so just call toBuilder() method on the returned pojo objects and return that instead of copying stuff over .

```
    List<Finding.Builder> findingResult = findings.stream().map(finding -> finding.toBuilder())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return findingResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It's caused by lacking of `getter` and `setter` methods in an amazon object bean.
2. By default , a setter method should start with `set` like `setPropName()`,but its'not in amazon object bean.
3. Meanwhile ,Jackson-json required the getter/setter methods in the pattern of `getPropName`| `setPropName`. And this's where the crash happens.
4. How to fix this ?
   Assuming we got an amazon object bean, `software.amazon.awssdk.services.organizations.model.Account`.

```java
final List<Account> accounts = response.accounts();
// call its toBuilder() method,
// and it returns a BuilderImpl ,which dose have standard getter/setter methods
List<Account.Builder> list = accounts.stream().map(a -> a.toBuilder()).collect(Collectors.toList());
// this list now can be jackson serialized properly 
return list;
```

[image]

5. finally ,test it with postman.As you can see,the result is fine

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems that all you need to do is set field visibility to any, as AWS SDK v2 classes have private fields and getters without "get" that are unrecognized. Serializing using private fields seems to work.

If you are using spring boot, add to your **application.yml** file this:

```
spring:
  jackson:
    visibility:
      field: any
```