# How to return response of JSONArray in Jackson framework rest api's?

Tags: java, jackson, jersey-2.0, jackson2

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getData(@QueryParam("id") long id) throws Exception {
    JSONArray json = (getting some json data from db)
    ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();
    return Response.ok(obj.writeValueAsString(json)).build();
}
```

I am trying to return the json array like this but getting error like this.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONArray and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
```

Can anyone help me with serialize this and provide the response. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Take a look at similar question with another 3rd party lib [How to return N1qlQueryResult as the response of REST API for Couchbase databse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55179768/how-to-return-n1qlqueryresult-as-the-response-of-rest-api-for-couchbase-databse/55180945#55180945). You do not need to convert object to `JSON` manually. `MVC` layer should do that for you. In case no, there must be a way, check documentation. If you do not have a `POJO` you can always create a `Map` to represent `JSON Object` and `List` or `array` to represent [JSON Array](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).

Comment: You need to register the [json-org module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatypes-misc/tree/master/json-org) with the ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring then you don't need `JSONArray`, just create a simple POJO class with all the `getter` and `setter` and use ObjectMapper to parse the JSON into that object, and then write the POJO class to response, as given below:

```
public ResponseEntity<DummyObject> getData(@QueryParam("id") long id) throws Exception 
    DummyPojo obj = mapper.readValue(json, DummyPojo.classs);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(obj)
}

// Replace DummyObject with your class
```

Spring will automatically converts into json, please check this link for more [info](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)

Comment: i agree with your answer and i'm aware of that. But here my requirement is to do without POJO class.

Comment: But problem with JSONObject and JSONArray is that they cannot be converted into json as they do not have getter/setter or any other way which Jackson uses to deserialize/serialize to json and Jackson is default registered as json serializer/deserializer so It would be difficult to achieve and may require some addional config or code.

Comment: If you have json string already do not convert it to JSONArray or JSONObject, just write it to response directly and return String from the function, that should work.